# jqGrid column freezing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have been using [Trirand's jqGrid](http://trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx) with ASP.NET MVC3 as well as the jquery.jqgrid plugin.

I have read that the **column freezing** feature is yet to be implemented and is up for voting.
But right now, I would like to dig into possible workarounds as compared to wait for the feature. Does somebody know of one or suggest a way to  approach this?

Thanks a lot for your inputs in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the feature:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:frozencolumns

Comment: Yes there is the feature now, but not at Dec 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know in which release of jqGrid the feature will be included, but I read in [the following post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/new-freeze-column-plugin/) about one workaround. To tell the truth I didn't yet tested the suggested solution. Hopefully it could help you.

Comment: Thanks for that link. :) Looks like a good place to start even though the author admits to some bugs.

Comment: That code there didn't help. Still waiting for it to appear in subsequent releases. :(

Comment: @conqenator: I don't think that you will see the feature in the next release because on the GitHub (see https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) it is not yet implemented. So you will have to wait probably a little more...